# Trying to make Email verification in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, email-verification

I've got an error

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265: Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [ #0]

May know what's the meaning of this? Glad that you could help me. thank you ^^

Comment: which client are you using to send a verification email? May be adding your `config/mail.php` code and .`.env` content will be helpful.

Comment: I aready set my mail.php and .env but it's the same result T__T

Comment: If you use the same credentials to trigger email in some smtp program, does the mail gets delivered without any error ? This is to make sure that your credentials is right..

Comment: unfortunately no... T__T it didn't delivered to the email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailing configuration can been seen at 2 places:

1. .env file
2. mail.php file located in `config` folder

You can update either of them, but it is **strictly recommended** to edit the `.env` file so as to avoid touching the default configurations.

Open `.env` file. You will see the `mail` configs in the bottom like so:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Now, login to your `mailtrap.io` account. From the `Integrations` dropdown, you need to select the `Laravel` option. When selected, the configs are provided below like this:

```
return array(
  "driver" => "smtp",
  "host" => "mailtrap.io",
  "port" => 2525,
  "from" => array(
      "address" => "from@example.com",
      "name" => "Example"
  ),
  "username" => "your_username",
  "password" => "your_password",
  "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs",
  "pretend" => false
);
```

Now open the `mail.php` file:

Go down to line number 57, it should have `'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],`. You need to replace this with what is provided in the `mailtrap.io` config.

So the updated `from` should be `'from' => ['address' => 'from@example.com', 'name' => 'Example'],`.

Now, in your `.env` file, update the `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD` with the `your_username` and `your_password` respectively.

So, your mailing config in `.env` file should like:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=your_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Done. You should now see the mails functioning without any further issues. Hope this helps you out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to set mailing provider details in .env file or you can add in config/mail.php

## **.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=test pass
MAIL_FROM=test@gmail.com
MAIL_NAME=test
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Please check this article... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sending-an-email-on-laravel-5